# Create groups and add group members from tfvars and assign keyvault access policies

Tags: azure, terraform

I had a very simple script (the one below) which creates a group owned by the terraform service principal and adds a group member specified by its user principal name (UPN). I wanted to expand its capabilities by specifying multiple groups and multiple group members in the `dev.tfvars` file. It works but since I'm new to terraform I wonder if I did correctly, and also how do I add keyvault access policies capabilities to one of the groups?

```
# Fetch the current Azure AD client configuration
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

# Create an Azure AD Group named "Developers"
resource "azuread_group" "devs" {
  display_name     = "Developers"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

# Fetch the details of a specific user by their UPN
data "azuread_user" "specific_user" {
  user_principal_name = "info@site.com"
}

# Add the specific user as a member of the "Developers" group
resource "azuread_group_member" "member" {
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.devs.object_id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.specific_user.object_id
}
```

### Snippet

```
// variables.tf
variable "groups" {
  description = "List of groups to create"
  type = list(object({
    display_name = string
    users        = list(string) # User Principal Names (UPNs)
  }))
}

//dev.tfvars
groups = [
  {
    display_name = "ProdDev_Software_Developers",
    users        = ["info@site.com", "john@NETORGFT11072195.onmicrosoft.com"]
  },
  {
    display_name = "Fin_Financial_Analysts",
    users        = ["info@site.com", "john@NETORGFT11072195.onmicrosoft.com"]
  }
]

// user_groups.tf
locals {
  group_user_pairs = flatten([
    for group in var.groups : [
      for user in group.users : {
        display_name = group.display_name
        user         = user
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "azuread_group" "group" {
  for_each = { for group in var.groups : group.display_name => group }

  display_name     = each.key
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for item in local.group_user_pairs : "${item.display_name}:${item.user}" => item }

  user_principal_name = each.value.user
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "group_member" {
  for_each = { for item in local.group_user_pairs : "${item.display_name}:${item.user}" => item }

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.group[each.value.display_name].object_id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].object_id
}
```

### Access policies that I want to add

My script also creates a keyvault, and I basically want to wait for it to create it and separately try to get the already created keyvault, and add these access policies in there.

All I wanted to do is create a group and give "List" permissions because I cannot list the secrets in the keyvault I created. There might be a better idea using RBAC, I'm not sure.

```
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = var.devs_group_object_id
    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Update",
      "Create",
      "Import",
      "Delete",
      "Recover",
      "Backup",
      "Restore"
    ]
    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "Set",
      "List",
      "Delete",
      "Recover",
      "Backup",
      "Restore"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to Create groups and add group members from tfvars and assign key vault access policies and I was able to provision them successfully using Terraform.

As per the requirement, my terraform code structure goes as follows for the creation of groups with users.

**variable.tf**

```
 variable "groups" {
  description = "List of groups to create"
  type = list(object({
    display_name = string
    users        = list(string) # User Principal Names (UPNs)
  }))
}
```

**dev.tfvars**

```
groups = [
  {
    display_name = "GroupVK",
    users        = ["testkavya@m365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com", "testdemo1@M365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com"]
  },
  {
    display_name = "GroupSB",
    users        = ["testkavya@m365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com", "testdemo1@M365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com"]
  }
]
```

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  group_user_pairs = flatten([
    for group in var.groups : [
      for user in group.users : {
        display_name = group.display_name
        user         = user
      }
    ]
  ])
}

// Fetch the current Azure AD client configuration
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_group" "group" {
  for_each = { for group in var.groups : group.display_name => group }

  display_name     = each.key
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for item in local.group_user_pairs : "${item.display_name}:${item.user}" => item }

  user_principal_name = each.value.user
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "group_member" {
  for_each = { for item in local.group_user_pairs : "${item.display_name}:${item.user}" => item }

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.group[each.value.display_name].object_id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].object_id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once we are done with the creation of groups with multiple users then
we need to create a key vault with `RBAC role access` or `access policy

my terraform configuration for key vault access goes as follows.

**keyvault.tf**

```
# Fetch the current Azure AD client configuration
 data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "GroupVK"
  security_enabled = true
 }
 
 # Fetch the details of a specific user by their UPN
data "azuread_user" "specific_user" {
  user_principal_name = "testkavya@m365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com"
}

    
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "demovenkat"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "v-bolliv"
  sku_name            = "standard"
  tenant_id           = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
}


# Add access policies to the Key Vault
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    =  data.azuread_user.specific_user.object_id

    key_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "List",
    "Update",
    "Create",
    "Import",
    "Delete",
    "Recover",
    "Backup",
    "Restore",
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "List",
    "Set",
    "Delete",
    "Recover",
    "Backup",
    "Restore",
  ]
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! :) I'm using RBAC now instead of access policies. They seem to be obsolete.